# Is there a smarter Way to address several Columns

Tags: excel, vba

I want to extract Data in a table. I use the TextToColumns feature. 
I Know it is 4 entries long. I might have data to the right. (Depending on who is doing the data excerpt). 
I want to insert the 4 Columns

I now have 4 lines of inserting a new column.

```
.Columns(searchCol + 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
.Columns(searchCol + 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
.Columns(searchCol + 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
.Columns(searchCol + 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```

Is there a smarter more elegant way to do that? 
(My code is running and working it is just about finesse)

Comment: Maybe a Loop ?  'For i = 1 To 4'

Comment: Are you using a delimiter when splitting your data? If so, you might use UBound(Split(targetText, delimiter)) when forming your for loop. If you are using TextLength you might use something like Len(targetText)/textLengthLimit in your for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To insert 4 columns at once left of column `searchCol + 1`:

```
.Columns(searchCol + 1).Resize(ColumnSize:=4).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```